# RegEx look-behind '(?<=\n|\A)' does not work because of variable length

Tags: regex, python-3.x, lookbehind

I use Python (3) and need a regular expression that matches at the beginning of the string or right after a newline.

I must add the `re.DOTALL` flag though because I need to process multiple lines at once. The example here is just simplified.

What I came up with is this lookbehind:

```
(?<=\n|\A)start of line
```

I tested it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iA3jY8/1) where it works, but running it in my Python 3.5 console leads to this error traceback:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160330] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\n|\A)start of line', 'just any text to test', re.DOTALL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 173, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 540, in compile
    code = _code(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 525, in _code
    _compile(code, p.data, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 158, in _compile
    raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
>>>
```

What can I use instead to overcome this limitation?

Comment: Using `re.DOTALL` doesn't keep you from using `re.MULTILINE`. With this it is just `^pattern`.

Comment: Just fyi. You don't need to use a lookbehind for `\A` which is zero-length. Instead of `(?<=\n|\A)` you could use  [`(?:(?<=\n)|\A)`](https://regex101.com/r/zN5qN3/1) but as answered multiline with `^` is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\A` is not a character, the error message makes sense.

Try this instead

```
re.search(r'^start of line', 'just any text to test', re.MULTILINE)
```

DOTALL is only relevant when you use `.` in your regular expression.

Maybe regex101 uses the third party [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package instead of re from the standard library.

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.search(r'(?<=\n|\A)line', 'test\nline')
<regex.Match object; span=(5, 9), match='line'>
```

As you can see, *regex* accepts variable width lookbehind patterns.

Comment: Yes, I know that I would not need the DOTALL in this example, but my real one is more complicated and matches there span multiple lines. However, the MULTILINE flag plus `^` as pattern works, thanks.

Comment: Regex101 uses something different from `regex` PyPi module. It is just buggy with Python option.

Comment: regex101 implements Python flavor with PCRE engine, by preventing regex with features not available in Python from running. It works for most of the cases, except for some corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use the multiline flag, which causes `^` and `$` to match every start and end of line respectively, thus making your regex just:

```
^
```